# what is stopping the random num generator from randomizing every time a player starts a new game?

Tags: c++, random

```
{
    int i,game = 0,guess,count = 0;

    int rando;
        

        srand (time(0));

        rando = rand() % 50 + 1;
    

        cout << "****Welcome To The Game****\n";
        cout << "1: Start the game\n";
        cout << "2: End the game\n";
        cin >> game; 

    while (game != 2 && count != 11)
    {

        cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 50: ";
        cin >> guess;

        count++;

        if(guess == rando)
        {
            cout << "you got it!\n";

            cout << "would you like to play again?\n";
            cin >> game; 
        }
    
        else if(guess < rando)
        {
            cout << "too low, try again " << endl;
        }
            
        else if(guess > rando)
        {
            cout << "Too high, try again" << endl;
        }
            
        
        if (count == 11)
        {
            cout << "too many guesses. the number was: " << rando << "." << endl;

            cout << "would you like to play again?\n";
            cin >> game; 
        }
        
        if (game == 2)
        {
            cout << "@@@ Thank you. See you next time.@@@\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I start the game, it generates a new number every time I run the program, but not when I ask to play again. I tried putting it in the while, but that messes up the code. how do I fulfill the second option in the first sentence?

Comment: You need to get a new random number each time you want to play a new game.  Do you have a line of code that does that *inside* the loop?

Comment: When wanting to play again, you are still in the while loop. Either you need to break out of it  and start the whole game again or you need to put the generation of the number in the loop.

Comment: It looks like you need to polish your code a bit, but also if you are using a Debug release in Visual Studio rand isn't that random, to help you debug.

Comment: @NathanOliver when i add the line of code inside the loop the program doesn't function correctly. when I added it in, for example, I could guess 12 and get a "too low" response even though the number was 4.

Comment: @CodeGorilla debug vs. release isn't a deterministic factor in the prng of the VC runtime; seeding *is*.  Unless seeded (`srand( something entropic )`) the default runtime action in *both* debug and release is equivalent to `srand(1)`, and that isn't specific to VC; it's part of the language standard. The OP's problem is they only draw one random number

Comment: @30for30 My crystal ball tells me you put it in the wrong place in the loop. It should be only in the specific if-clauses dealing with starting a new game. there are two such cases in your code : `if(guess == rando)` and `if (count == 11)`

Comment: It looks like you have a single loop that controls both "repeatedly guessing until I win or run out of guesses" _and_ "repeatedly play rounds until I choose to quit". You need to generate a new random number every time the latter occurs, but keep it the same between iterations of the former. That's tricky while both loops are mashed together like you have here. Split it out into an outer loop for whether to play another round or quit, and an inner loop to guess, and then you'll have a single place you can change the value of the target.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: @NathanPierson thank you for giving me help on the design of the program. I am planning to try a whole new approach with a for loop instead of the while and separating as you said

Comment: @WhozCraig when I use your answer, is there a way to make the count reset to 0 each time the game runs again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int randomGame()
{
    int gameMenuChoice = 0;

    srand(time(0));

    std::cout << "****Welcome To The Game****\n";
    std::cout << "1: Start the gameMenuChoice\n";
    std::cout << "2: End the gameMenuChoice\n";
    std::cin >> gameMenuChoice;

    while (gameMenuChoice != 2)
    {
        const int rando = rand() % 50 + 1;
        int guess = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < 11 && guess != rando; ++count)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 50: ";
            std::cin >> guess;
            if (guess < rando)
            {
                std::cout << "too low, try again \n";
            }
            else if (guess > rando)
            {
                std::cout << "Too high, try again\n";
            }
        }
        if (guess == rando)
        {
            std::cout << "you got it!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "too many guesses. the number was: " << rando << ".\n";
        }
        std::cout << "would you like to play again?\n";         // I think people will enter Y for yes here.
        std::cin >> gameMenuChoice;
    }
    std::cout << "@@@ Thank you. See you next time.@@@\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I have split you menu and game routine loops and simplified the logic a bit.